# Computation of a derivative in a Banach algebra

Tags: derivatives, harmonic-functions, banach-algebras

Let A be a complex unital Banach algebra with the unit e and φ : A → A a continuous antilinear mapping such that φ(exp(x)) is invertible, for every x in A.
Let f be the following map:
f(λ) = [φ(exp(λx))]y[φ(exp(λx))]−1

1. How can I compute the derivative of f by λ, where λ lies is a complex number. I don't know how to compute the derivative of [φ(exp(λx))]−1.
2. How can I show that f is harmonic?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.